# Jquery Ajax Post but expected PHP code not running

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to set up a simple webpage on a local server. This webpage has a button, and when the button is pressed on a local client I expect a directory to be created on the server. PHP is run on the server side, whereas jquery is run on the client side.

My PHP code in test.php: `<?php mkdir('/home/pablo/test_dir', 0777, true); ?>`

The jquery/ajax in script.js:

```
var toggleOutlet = function(buttonClicked) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Directory created!');
        }
    });
};
$(function() {
    $('.toggleOutlet').click(function() {
        toggleOutlet($(this));
    });
});
```

When I press the button on a client, I do get a "Directory created!" alarm, but no test_dir is created on the server. What am I doing wrong??
For completeness, my html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>MyWeb</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <label>Example Button</label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" data-outletId="1" data-outletStatus="on" class="btn btn-default toggleOutlet">On</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that your web client has write permissions on this directory? Also, can you post back the data you get from your response? An error code may be sent back.

Comment: Hi. Do you know who should be the owner of /home/pablo so /home/pablo/test_dir is created? I've given full permissions 777 to ~, and tried adding www-data to the pablo group, but I don't know if this is what you mean. Also I'm not seeing any error codes so far, but I'm trying to figure that out

Comment: if you’re using chrome you can use the network tab in chrome and inspect the post request (probably better) and the console must be up when the request is made or the network tab won’t record it.

Comment: Did what you said, and got an "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3". Solved this by changing the version, but still no folder created...

Comment: That doesn’t make sense because you shouldn’t get that kind of error code from test.php

Comment: true, I got that error when loading the website. From test.php, in the Response tab I get no errors, just the code itself: `<?php mkdir('/home/pablo/test_dir', 0777, true); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Hello @pablo919 You need check if the directory "/home/pablo" it have write´s permissions other thing you can change the code ajax and add function error for check what is.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Directory created!');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }

    });
```

Comment: I did give full permissions to the parent directory (/home/pablo) with `chmod 777`, owner `pablo` but still `test_dir` is not created when I press the button. Is this what you meant with checking permissions?

Comment: Also, I added the error code in script.js as you mentioned... Sorry for the question, but should I see an error message when I press the button from a client? So far I'm still seeing a window with the "Directory created!" message but nothing else